# Are Orthogonal Basis perpendicular to Original Basis in Gram-Schmidt?

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

a, b and c are 3 Independent Vectors. We can generate Orthonormal basis vectors using those 3 vectors using Gram-Schmidt method. Lets say those 3 orthogonal basis vectors generated from a, b and c are $A$, $B$ and $C$. We can generate orthonormal basis vectors by dividing those orthogonal basis vectors with their length.

I am trying to figure out if $C$ will be orthogonal to b (which is one of the original basis vector). It seems like it should be, because $C$ is orthogonal to the plane containing a and b. Is there any way to prove this? I am trying to use the approach below and going into calculations which don't look pretty.
$$C = c - \frac{(A^Tc)A}{A^TA} - \frac{(B^Tc)B}{B^TB}$$
Multiplying both sides by $b^T$. Idea is to show $b^TC = 0$  to demonstrate orthogonality

$$b^TC = b^Tc - \frac{(A^Tc)b^TA}{A^TA} - \frac{(B^Tc)b^TB}{B^TB}$$

Using
$$B = b - \frac{(A^Tb)A}{A^TA}$$

$$b^TC = b^Tc - \frac{(A^Tc)b^TA}{A^TA} - \frac{\left(b - \frac{(A^Tb)A}{A^TA}\right)^Tcb^T\left(b - \frac{(A^Tb)A}{A^TA}\right)}{B^TB}$$

I am not sure if I need to follow through on this or am I headed in the wrong direction? Thank you.

Comment: Just a minor comment: A few times, you say "basis" when you should say "basis vectors." For example "We can generate orthonormal basis by dividing those orthogonal basis with their length" should be "We can generate orthonormal basis by dividing those orthogonal basis **vectors** by their length."

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed the case. If we have a sequence of vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$, and obtain $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ from the Gram-Schmidt procedure, then it has the additional (sometimes overlooked) property that
$$\operatorname{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_i\} = \operatorname{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_i\}. \tag{$\star$}$$
In particular, since $e_{i+1}$ is perpendicular to each vector in $\{e_1, \ldots, e_i\}$, and hence to each vector in $\operatorname{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_i\}$, it will also be perpendicular to each vector in $\operatorname{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_i\}$, including $v_1, \ldots, v_i$. That is, each vector we obtain from Gram-schmidt will be orthogonal to every previous vector in the list.

To prove $(\star)$, it is best to use induction. Note that $e_1 = v_1$, so $\operatorname{span}\{v_1\} = \operatorname{span}\{e_1\}$. That is, the base case holds.

Suppose $(\star)$ holds when $i = k$. We have
$$e_{k+1} = v_{k+1} - \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{v_{k+1}^\top e_i}{e_i^\top e_i} e_i.$$
Note that the subtracted sum lies in $\operatorname{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_k\}$, which is equal to $\operatorname{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$, by assumption. Thus the sum is a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_k$, which makes $e_{k+1}$ a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_{k+1}$. That is,
$$e_{k+1} \in \operatorname{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_{k+1}\}.$$
By assumption, $e_1, \ldots, e_k$ all lie in the smaller space $\operatorname{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$, and so they also lie in the large space. Hence
$$\operatorname{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_{k+1}\} \subseteq \operatorname{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_{k+1}\}.$$
On the other hand,
$$v_{k+1} = e_{k+1} + \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{v_{k+1}^\top e_i}{e_i^\top e_i} e_i \in \operatorname{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_{k+1}\},$$
and $v_1, \ldots, v_k \in \operatorname{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_k\}$, by assumption, thus
$$\operatorname{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_{k+1}\} = \operatorname{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_{k+1}\},$$
completing the induction proof.

Comment: Thank you so much Theo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if we have linearly independent vectors $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ and we apply Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization moving from left to right, resulting in $X_1,\ldots, X_n$, then each $X_k$ will be orthogonal to $x_1,\ldots, x_{k-1}$.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that the vector space is question is $V=\text{span}\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$ (in general, we could be working in a larger space  $X$ such that $\text{span}\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}\subsetneq X$, but the larger space is irrelevant in this context).

For $k=1,\ldots, n$, let $W_k=\text{span}\{x_1,\ldots, x_k\}$. for any subset $S$ of $V$, let $$S^\perp = \{x\in V:(\forall y\in S)(y\cdot x=0)\}.$$ So $S^\perp$ is the set of things orthogonal to everything in $S$. As you said, we'll be interested in the case when $S$ is a plan (the plane spanned by $a,b$). The key point is that the plane spanned by $a,b$ is the same as the plane spanned by $A,B$. It is difficult to reconstruct this "after the fact." It's much easier to prove it as part of the Gram-Schmidt process.

The steps to Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization will be to recursively select $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ in such a way that $W_k=\text{span}\{x_1,\ldots, x_k\}=\text{span}\{X_1,\ldots, X_k\}$ and $X_{k+1}\in W_k^\perp$. The first equality $W_k=\text{span}\{x_1,\ldots, x_k\}$ holds by definition.

> Note:  Fix $x\in V$ and a non-empty subset $S$ of $V$. If $x\cdot y=0$ for all $y\in S$, then $x\cdot y=0$ for all $y\in \text{span}(S)$. That's because if $y\in \text{span}(S)$, then $y=\sum_{i=1}^m a_iy_i$ for some $m$, some scalars $a_i$, and some $y_i\in S$. Then $$x\cdot y = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i x\cdot y_i=\sum_{i=1}^m a_i\cdot 0=0.$$ So being in $W_k^\perp$ is equivalent to being orthogonal to every member of a spanning set of $W_k$. So if we know that $W_k=\text{span}\{x_1,\ldots, x_k\}=\text{span}\{X_1,\ldots, X_k\}$ and that $X_{k+1}\cdot X_i=0$ for all $i\leqslant k$, then we know that $X_{k+1}$ is orthogonal to every member of $\text{span}\{X_1,\ldots, X_k\}$ (that is, $X_{k+1}\in W_k^\perp$), and therefore it is orthogonal to $x_1,\ldots, x_k$, these these are in $W_k$.

The only thing left to do is show how Gram-Schmidt maintains $\text{span}\{x_1,\ldots, x_k\}=\text{span}\{X_1,\ldots, X_k\}$. Let $Y_1,\ldots, Y_n$ be the orthogonal vectors resulting from Gram-Schmidt, so that $X_i=Y_i/\|Y_i\|$, where $\|Y_i\|$ denotes the length of $Y_i$. It is obvious that $$\text{span}\{X_1,\ldots, X_k\}=\text{span}\{Y_1,\ldots, Y_k\},$$ so we only need to show that $$\text{span}\{x_1,\ldots, x_k\}=\text{span}\{Y_1,\ldots, Y_k\}$$ for all $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$.  For this, we'll us something that depends only on the algebra, not on the geometry (orthogonality or normalization).

> Proposition: Suppose that $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ is a basis for the vector space $V$. Suppose also that $u_1,\ldots, u_n\in V$ are vectors such that for all $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, $$u_k=v_k+w_k$$ for some $w_k\in \text{span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_{k-1}\}$. (By convention, when $k=1$, $\{u_1,\ldots, u_{k-1}\}=\varnothing$ and the span of this set is $\{0\}$. In particular, $w_1=0$ and $u_1=v_1$.) Then $\text{span}\{u_1,\ldots, u_k\}=\text{span}\{v_1,\ldots, v_k\}$ for all $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$.

Before proving the proposition, we note that it applies to the Gram-Schmidt process, because we orthogonalize by keeping $Y_1=x_1$, and then $$Y_k=x_k-P_{k-1}x_k,$$ where $P_{W_{k-1}}x_k$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\text{span}\{Y_1,\ldots, Y_{k-1}\}$ ($P_1$ is the zero operator). Since $P_{k-1}x_k\in \text{span}\{X_1,\ldots, X_{k-1}\}$, the proposition applies.

It's also worth noting that the proposition can be reformulated as a statement about the inverses of triangular matrices with $1$s on the main diagonal. It's also worth noting that we don't need the assumption of $1$s on the main diagonal (that is, we can have $u_k=\color{red}{c_k}v_k+w_k$ instead of $u_k=\color{red}{1}v_k+ w_k$), as long as each $c_k$ is non-zero. But that case easily reduces to the case of $1$s on the diagonal by dividing the equations by $c_k$.

Let's prove the proposition by induction. For $k=1$, $u_1=v_1$, so $\text{span}\{u_1\}=\text{span}\{v_1\}$.

Suppose $1<k\leqslant n$ and $W:=\text{span}\{v_1,\ldots, v_{k-1}\}=\text{span}\{u_1,\ldots, u_{k-1}\}$.   Then since $$u_k=v_k+w_k$$ and $$w_k\in W,$$ there exist some scalars $(a_j)_{j=1}^{k-1}$, $(b_j)_{j=1}^{k-1}$ such that $$w_k=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}a_j v_j=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}b_ju_j.$$  Then if $$x\in \text{span}\{v_1,\ldots, v_k\},$$ we can write $$x=\sum_{j=1}^k c_k v_j=c_kv_k+x',$$ where $x'\in W$. Then $$x=c_kv_k+x'=c_k(u_k-w_k)+x' = c_ku_k+(x'-c_kw_k)\in \text{span}\{u_1,\ldots, u_k\},$$ since $x'-c_kw_k\in W=\text{span}\{u_1,\ldots, u_{k-1}\}$.   Similarly, if $x\in \text{span}\{u_1,\ldots, u_k\}$, we can write $$x=\sum_{j=1}^k d_ju_j=d_ku_k+x'',$$ where $x''\in W$. Then $$x=d_k(v_k+w_k)+x''=d_kv_k+(x''+d_kw_k)\in \text{span}\{v_1,\ldots, v_k\},$$ since $x''+d_kw_k\in W$.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting in effort and answering it in detail. :)